# Wordfence monitors some strange actions from www.Your-Website-Sucks.net

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A few weeks ago my website was hacked. So I decided to delete and reconfigure the whole Wordpress website and increase the security. After some research, I found a plugin named Wordfence which can monitor and trace all actions on the website. When I have a look at the log of the plugin, I found many actions with the following description:

... arrived from http://www.Your-Website-Sucks. net/WWW.example.COM and visited https://example.COM/ 14-3-2018 01:25:47 (4 hours ago)
IP: 54.37.78.164 Hostname: hehehe.your-website-sucks. net Browser: undefined Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Your-Website-Sucks/2.0; +http://www.Your-Website-Sucks. net/WWW.example.COM)

I am a bit concerned about this because of the name 'www.your-website-sucks. net' isn't sound good. Is there anyone who knows this site and what to do against this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, WordFence is brilliant. I use it on all the websites I design. So keep using it.
Secondly, I have also been noticing lately across multiple websites that I have been getting visitors from www.Your-Website-Sucks.net/...
I don't think there is a need for immediate concern - at the end of the day it is just a referrer, meaning they came to the site FROM that page.
My guess is that it is some sort of bot - perhaps it is a new marketing technique to get them noticed?
I know that every hack attempt I have had (not necessarily from anyone to do with www.Your-Website-Sucks.net) has been blocked by WordFence, so no matter where the attack comes from, if WordFence continues to do its job then we are ok. 
I have tried to find out more information regarding www.Your-Website-Sucks.net, but I can't seem to find much, meaning it is probably a new thing that is happening. 
But I wouldn't worry - you aren't alone.

Answer (score 0):

it seems  that Your-Website-Sucks.net was registered at namecheap.com and hosted on a OVH server

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/54.36.113.23

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/54.36.112.0

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/54.36.113.4

and finally

https://www.whois.com/whois/54.36.113.23